# iAd Banner View control not found on xcode 8 interface builder

Tags: xcode8

Hello Guys I want to integrate iAd Banner View in my app.I am using xcode 8 but I will found that iAd Banner View is no more available now.
What should I do know??[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer. Apple iAd no longer available from 1 July 2016.
 [image]